# Likes not loading on photos from private accounts using Instagram API

Tags: api, instagram

Likes not loading on photos from private accounts using the Instagram API. Same access token works fine to load likes on photos from non private accounts. The user for this access token is following the private account and can see the profile and photos just fine. It displays this error:

```js
{
    "meta": {
        "error_type":"APINotFoundError",
        "code":400,
        "error_message":"invalid media id"
    }
}
```

Comment: just try to be more precise on your question. private accounts of what? likes from where? where are you getting this meta string.....

Comment: sorry i thought i had tagged it instagram, fixed. thank you

Comment: I can confirm this bug.

Comment: I, too, can confirm the bug.  I find that private accounts can't even view the likes on their own photos with the API call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is an actual Instagram API bug on this endpoint, not specific to a token or a client id.
I reproduced this easily, setting my account as private and testing on several services (such as statigram or webstagram). And if a set my account as public, all is ok.

We have reported this issue using the bug tool (from http://instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/). We have thousands of examples of this, so it seems to be global.

I hope it will be fixed soon. It is not the most critical endpoint of the API, but of course it is better if it runs ;-)

Comment: I also reported it a day or two ago.  No response from Instagram as yet, but I guess I've been trained to expect that.

Comment: there is no public facing bug tracker, to monitor status of bugs.. correct?

Comment: and we still have this issue